# Facebook API 4.0: How to avoid "This authorization code has expired"?

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

On my website I use the facebook javascript SDK to initialize and login the user, and later once the user has responded to the survey and submitted it on the website, i fetch the facebook user on the server side using facebook PHP SDK. This works great, except for the case when the user connects to my app then leaves the page open for a while, to later comeback and attempt submit the survey. If the user waits long enough, I will get the "This authorization code has expired" error on the PHP server side, i'm not sure how to solve this.

Is there some way to refresh the authorization code through javascript SDK? I assume it is generated on FB.init. The optimal thing would be if i could make a check before the submit to see if the authorization code is still valid, then if not i would refresh it and fire the submit event.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this may be to use `FB.getLoginStatus` of the JavaScript right before the server call - it refreshes the Access Token and you can get it in the response:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus